# finite generation of intersection of subgroups

Tags: group-theory

I am stuck on the following:
let $G$ be a  finitely generated group and $H$, $K$ be two non-trivial subgroups. Suppose $H\cap K$ is finitely generated. Let $g\in G$ be a non-trivial element. Is $H\cap gKg^{-1}$ finitely generated?

If $H\cap gKg^{-1}$ is trivial then there is nothing to check. So assume that $H\cap gKg^{-1}$ is non-trivial.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are counterexamples. You can construct one using any finitely generated group $B$ that contains some non-finitely generated subgroup $A$.

Consider $G = (B \times B) \rtimes \langle \phi \rangle$, where $\phi$ is the automorphism which swaps the two factors.

Then $G$ is a finitely generated. For $H = A \times 1$ and $K = 1 \times A$ we have $H \cap K = 1$ finitely generated, but $H \cap \phi K \phi^{-1} = H$ is not finitely generated.